# Overwriting Feature Service to webmap does not update with new data in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, update, feature-service

This is cross posted to geonet as well: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/196111-updating-feature-service-to-webmap-does-not-update-with-new-data

I have a web feature service on a web map and that map shared through an web app.
This service is just a small point layer and I update it every month with updated points. I then upload the layer to agol using the "overwrite" option on my existing point feature service. However my web map does not update with the new points automatically. I have to re-add the service as a new layer and remove the previous one in addition to manually copying my pop-up configs over to the new layer.
I was under the impression the overwriting the service would in turn have the updates roll out to the web map layer. Am I missing a step here or is this how the overwrite feature works?

[Russ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/53550/russ-roberts) lead me to the correct answer to solve this issue. I just needed to set my refresh interval Support docs can be found here: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/set-refresh-interval.htm

Comment: Are you refreshing the map or using refresh interval to pickup the changes? Are you changing the schemas at all? I wasn't able to reproduce the issue Using ArcMap - Published Feature Layer of Points with editing enabled, created Web Map, In ArcMap with the Same Feature Class deleted Features, Share As ->Overwrite and pick the service published initially and share the service. Then Refresh the page and see the points have been deleted.

Comment: I have my browser closed initially. After I successfully upload the feature service overwrite I then open browser, login AGOL, navigate to the webmap and it still displays the old points. Let me check out the refresh interval options but I figured it would grab whatever the service definition is and if it changes the map would therefore change as well.

Comment: Also check out the doc page to see if anything in your setup might cause an issue with bringing your changes over: http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/manage-hosted-feature-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1D3A87A80E3E4CD2A71744715F1522FE

Comment: refresh interval did the trick.... simple as that :) thanks Russ!